# Handling touch event on menu item click

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I want to handle the touch event on click of menu item in the menu, and on click of spinner text in the spinner and on select date or on click ok button in a date control. OnUserInteraction() method is not triggered when click on these above items.

**Note:** Just to clearify, I *know* about **onClick event**. but like **onUserInteraction()**, whenever user touch the screen, I am notifed and I do some stuff. But this **event is not invoked** when user touches on extra **menu item**(which comes as drop down), **spinner drop down** and or **button click in dialog**.

So is there some way to be notified for the same. I know we have some event(I can say that coz screen brightness increase when left for some time and user touch any of the above mentioned item).

Can anybody tell me, is there is any other touch events available for handle this?

Thanks
Mindus

Comment: You should be able to find these when you research these objects respectively. For your menu: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#RespondingOptionsMenu

Comment: @mindus I have added some info on your question which I felt you wanted to communicate. Feel free to revert back if any thing is mis conveyed. thanks